# Appending div andshowing as a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append div element to existing div. This new div is used to generate dynamic table. Finally i want  to  display this dynamic table as dialog. Iam ntsure where i am going wrong. Pls guide me.

My html code

```
<div><div id="div1"><\div>
```

My jquery code

```
var x = document.getElementById('nav');

var rDiv = document.createElement('div');

x.appendChild(rDiv);
rdiv. id="dynamictable"
$('#dynamictable').append('<table></table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();    
table.append("<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>");
table.append("<tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>");
$('# dynamictable'). dialog()
```

Comment: Do you have more lines of HTML? You request an element by id 'nav' but that isn't present in your code.

Answer (score 0):

first fix the HTML...

```
<div><div id="div1"></div></div>
```

Second typo on the variable rDiv as rdiv

Last remove the space when you name "# dynamictable"